# How does Google protect their search service from being accessed?

Tags: web-services, security

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this. I've been trying to figure out a way to prevent someone from accessing my API and I was wondering this because I thought their techniques might be useful.

How does Google access their search services from their webpage? How do they protect their API with Ajax? I know they have ways of dealing with scrapers, but what about getting at their API directly?

Answer (score 0):

The standard technique is to rate limit by IP address. If you scrape Google sufficiently slowly and you have access to a large number of IP addresses, you **can** scrape them.

If you scrape too fast, they will ban your IP.

Comment: But what is google accessing directly from their web pages to retrieve this data, I couldn't seem to find it in their source code, unless it's  encrypted somehow.

Comment: @Anonymous, They could very well be passing a cookie, but when you make a request to Google using your browser, you are using *your* IP address. Since you are presumably accessing Google at human rates, they will allow the access.